# Create new number of List<T> out of one List<T> depending on T.variable

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm pretty sure the title sounds kind of weird but I hope this is a valid question :)

I have a class, let's call it Employee:

```
class Employee 
{
    int employeeid { get; set; }
    String employeename { get; set; }
    String comment { get; set; }
}
```

I will fill a List from a database. An employeeid can have X number of comments, thus leaving the ratio 1:X. And there can of course be Y number of employeeid as well.

I want to create a List out of all the employee-objects which has for example employeeid = 1. And another list out of employeeid = 2.

I can sort the original List by employeeid, loop through the list and create a new list each time I hit a new employeeid. However I feel that the performance could be better.

Is there a way to split the original List into X number of lists depending on X number of distinct employeeids?

Comment: So, employeeid is not the primary key? If it is, then your List<Employee> where employeeid = 1 will always contain only 1 object.

Comment: @TimB The name of the type is misleading; this item represents one comment by an employee, not the employee, so in this class it's a foreign key.

Comment: `I want to create a List out of all the employee-objects which has for example employeeid = 1` - Isn't EmployeeId supposed to be unique? - Anyways, what you're looking for is [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)

Comment: If an employee can have multiple comments shouldn't the `comment` property be a collection instead of a string?

Comment: @TimB: You are correct, it's misleading. I'm sorry about that. It should be Comment, with the employeeid as FK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
var query = data.GroupBy(employee => employee.employeeid);
```

Note the performance is much better than the algorithm you described.  It will use a hash based data structure for the IDs, meaning that the entire operation is effectively a single pass performing a constant-time operation on each item.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, LINQ's [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) should make this a breeze. Try something like that:

```
var answer = myEmployeeList.GroupBy( emp=>emp.employeeid );
```